# Extremely high disk I/O on gnome-terminal-server

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

gnome-terminal-server is always the top in system monitor when sorted by disk read or write, consuming several GiB, and keep growing. Is that normal? If it is normal, why is that? I think a terminal emulator needs not such huge disk IO.

Comment: This would not be something I've experienced. Is your terminal configured to run a shell script on startup?

Comment: @matigo No, I just reinstalled the OS in March, and the I haven't modified gnome terminal's startup behaviour. Thank you for your reply - I thought everyone has experienced the same at the beginning! Now I know that this doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single `gnome-terminal-server` process handles all your GNOME Terminal windows and tabs, therefore accounts for even the terminals that you have already closed (until you close all the tabs at windows at once, when this process quits).

The scrollback buffer is stored on disk in temporary files (don't worry, they are encrypted). So it's reasonable to see roughly as much disk activity as much data these terminals process.

Certain actions, like resizing the window (rewrapping the lines), or searching in the history, potentially require to read the corresponding terminal's entire scrollback data from disk (and writing some new data too, in case of rewrapping). Scrolling back might also be responsible for quite a few reads.

This should be pretty much all the activity you see from `gnome-terminal-server`; assuming that your monitoring software displays the amount which this process is directly responsible for, without aggregating all its descendants.